# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated?8

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, image

I am trying to save image file on db in binary format. I am using data set to write insert query. As a beginner I don't know how to use these things. While using the given below code get some errors. They are:
String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated

Please help me.

Code:

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet1TableAdapters.Tbl_EmpTableAdapter adp1;
        adp1 = new DataSet1TableAdapters.Tbl_EmpTableAdapter();
        adp1.GetInsert(txtEmpName.Text,FileUpload1);
    }
```

Source:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> &#10038</td>
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Insert Query:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_Emp (EmpName, EmpPic) VALUES (@EmpName,@EmpPic)
```

Data base:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try storing [`FileUpload.FileBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the entire upload control.

And to prevent your next question: please change the column type to `varbinary(max)` to be able to store files larger than 50 bytes.